# Git post-update hook "Not a directory" error

Tags: windows, git, post-update

I am trying to set up git post-update hook in windows environment. Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /c/inetpub/vhosts/mywebsite || exit
unset GIT_DIR
git pull hub master
exec git-update-server-info
```

When I run this from shell (sh post-update) everything works great. But after push I have an error:

```
hooks/post-update: line 7: cd: /c/inetpub/vhosts/mywebsite: Not a directory
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When you are in the *Git Bash* shell, what happens if you try to do `cd /c/inetpub/vhosts/mywebsite`?

Comment: Everything works as expected, current dir changed to /c/inetpub/vhosts/mywebsite.

Comment: what do you get if you do `echo $USER` in your shell, and if you put that in your hook script and do a push? Does it give the same thing? Also, if you change the absolute path of `/c/inetpub/vhosts/mywebsite` to a relative path, does that work? (For that, keep in mind that hook scripts are executed in the root directory of the repository, for example if your hook script is `/c/repos/repo.git/hooks/post-update` then it is executed in `/c/repos/repo.git`.)

Comment: Not sure I'am doing things right, but `echo $USER` gives me empty line both in shell and after push. Using relative path's gives me the same error `hooks/post-update: line 8: cd: ../../inetpub/vhosts/mywebsite: Not a directory`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the a different path, a relevant path. For example, your root path.

```
#!/bin/sh
unset GIT_DIR
cd ..
git checkout -f
```

Using `cd ..` to go back to your folder's root path. Then, the `git checkout -f` is used to force update the working copy every time the repo gets updated.

Comment: Getting error: "Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"